# How to properly transform json strings to objects

Tags: go, apache-beam

I have a Beam pipeline written in Go and I'd like to transform this input:

```
{"name": "Bob", "age": 32}
```

to a valid "object".

The go sdk has this function in the encoding package :

```
// UnmarshalJSON sets the state of this instance from the passed in JSON.
func (w *EncodedType) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t, err := graphx.DecodeType(s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    w.T = t
    return nil
}
```

But I don't understand how to use it as a step of my pipeline.

Comment: I feel that [this](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder_Decode_stream) example should help you. Could you show us where JSON records are returned by the pipeline? From there we should be able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sort of on the right track. Go doesn't have "objects" in the normal sense of the word as it pertains to programming. You would use a struct like this:

```golang
    type User struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Age     int    `json:"age"`
    }
```

You would use that to unmarshal into that structure like this:

```golang
    var myUser User
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"name": "Bob", "age": 32}`), &myUser)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(myUser.Name, myUser.Age)
```

Here is a playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/_uHZ9Q_j-p1

More information: https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go